# Can I tell if an Android device is moving from its current location?

Tags: android, gps, android-sensors

I'm new in Android and I would like to ask you is there any possible way to know if the Android phone moved about 5 meters from its current location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use the accelerometer to detect when the phone is moving. Naturally, you can't estimate the distance moved very accurately, but it might work for your application. If the accelerometer says the phone is moving for more than 5 seconds or so (maybe you can detect a pattern of movement?) you might infer that the phone moved significantly from its original position.

Of course, the user can trick your app by shaking the phone...

Answer (score 0):

A good resource concerning GPS can be found at the official site: http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/

The short answer, however, is that the GPS accuracy of a specific phone at a given moment is dependent upon several variables.  Those that are most pertinent to your question would be the actual hardware of the device, and the environmental conditions at present.  Typically, a phone under good conditions can expect at best 10m of lateral accuracy.  Taking into account poor conditions, local interference, limited satellite connectivity, etc, can push the error of a reading much higher.  Unfortunately, consistently and precisely measuring a movement of 5m is unlikely.

Comment: OK, If I use 10 m Can I implement that using SensorManager ?